# Automatically include javascript in Scaladoc using SBT

Tags: scala, sbt, mathjax, scaladoc

I am working on a library of mathematical functions. As part of the `Scaladoc`, I would like to include the formula of each function. E.g.

```
/**
 * Sum squared function:
 * \(f(x) = \sum_i^n x_i^2\)
 */
def sumSquared[T](x: Seq[T]) = x.map(xi => xi * xi).sum
```

I am using [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/) to display the formula. It works if I manually edit the generated html to include the required MathJax javascript, but I want to automate this.

So far the only solutions I've found are:

- [Is there a way to include math formulae in Scaladoc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15996651/is-there-a-way-to-include-math-formulae-in-scaladoc)
- [How to run bash script after generating scaladoc using doc task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15212472/how-to-run-bash-script-after-generating-scaladoc-using-doc-task)

If these are the only options then okay, however I'd like do this using only sbt (no external scripts). Is there a way to do this by maybe setting `scalacOptions` as in [How to ScalaDoc](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Howto-Scaladoc.html)?

Answer (score 1):

I added an answer to [Is there a way to include math formulae in Scaladoc?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32114551/1206998) with an sbt task that does the job, but still using MathJax.

I don't know of any code that would actually replace the latex formula to images in the generated api files